# Token and JWT with dotnet Core 3.1 User Identification, localStorage.getItem("token") is null

Tags: c#, angular

I can not get 'token' value from Angular App. it returns null.
Please any one pinpoint what I have done wrong.
Here is the code in startup.cs

```
 services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();               

            //Jwt Authentication

            var key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"].ToString());
            //services.AddAuthentication()
            services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(token =>
            {
                token.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                token.SaveToken = true;
                token.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            })
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();           
            //End of Jwt Authentication

            //services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

//here is the code from login.cshtml.cs

      public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                //
                // add JWT to create Token
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Yitong Create Token.");
                    // logic to get token from GenerateJSONWebToken
                    var tokenString = GenerateJSONWebToken();

                    // end changed
                    //_logger.LogInformation(tokenString);
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

       private string GenerateJSONWebToken()
        {
            var sec = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890123456");
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(sec);
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, User.Identity.Name)
            };
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
              "self", // issuer
              "self", // Audience
              null, // replace null with claims
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
              signingCredentials: credentials);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

here is my code in angular
to get data from sql server
the token is = null

```
getForeCast() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<forecastModel.weatherForecast_custom[]>(this.url, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log("HTTP request executed")),
        catchError(err => {
          console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        finalize(() => console.log("first finalize() block executed")),
      )
  };
```

Anyone please?
I don't know why I can not post this it says 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'

This is the best I can describe the issue I have had.
Thank you

Comment: where is the code in angular where you store the token in local storage ?

Comment: go to chrome console applications -> local storage to see if the token is stored properly

Comment: Show where you are setting the token